# Example of $\langle T(v),v \rangle =0$ for every $v$, but $T \neq 0$

Tags: inner-products

As it says in the title, I neeed an example of a linear transformation $T$, over $\mathbb{R}$ (not $\mathbb{C}$!), that satisfies $\langle T(v),v \rangle =0$ for every $v$ in $V$, but $T \neq 0$.

Any suggestions ?
Thanks :)

Comment: How about $T\colon (x,y)\mapsto (-y, x)$, i.e. $\pi/2$-rotation of the plane?

Comment: The previous editer (I don't recall the name) informs you that  over $\mathbb{C}$, $T$ has to be $0$. I'm putting this as a comment

Comment: Marcin, I don't know V's dimension

Comment: Well, since you asked for example, I assumed some one particular map for one particular space was what you need. What is it that you need, then? Construction for arbitrary real inner product space?

Comment: Question is not clear as it is written.... you should have mentioned where does $T(V)$ lies... Is it in $V$?? In general $\langle T(v),v\rangle$ does not make much sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such transformation if $\dim V=1$.

An example for $\dim V=2$ is given by Marcin Łoś: $T\colon (x,y)\mapsto (-y, x)$

If $\dim V>2$, take orthogonal projection $P$ onto some two-dimensional plane. Then compose it with two-dimensional $T$.

---

As an aside: if $\dim V$ is  even, such $T$ may be constructed so that it's invertible. If $\dim V$ is odd, any such $T$ has nontrivial kernel.